# When Webview load iframe and any page from that loaded iframe url, Share is not working in app

Tags: iframe, android-webview, share

I am loading webview in my android app. I have added addJavascriptInterface to my webview also. Previously I could track the share action from webview page (e.g. link1) to my app and open my desired printer app.

Now same webview is loading another iframe (same link1) from where share action is not working.

How can i trap the share action from iframe to webview andriod?

Thanks in advance.

//webView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebViewJavaScriptShareInterface(), "Android"); It is added.

My loaded webview after some work, goes to invoice page where there is share button. After clicking that share button, it call's Andriod.share and it was working fine.

Now my webview is loading another link inside iframe where after some work, goes to invoice page  (same link as before) where there is share button. After clicking that share button, it is saying "Share is not supported"